# query_posts works while get_posts doesn't

Tags: query-posts, get-posts

I try to create a page that shows my posts (a page different than the "posts page" defined in wp-admin).

When I copy my `index.php` into this new page and add

```
<?php query_posts('post_type=post&posts_per_page=5&paged='.get_query_var('paged')); ?>
```

above the

```
    <?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>
...
...
```

then everything works fine - my posts are shown. If I try to put

```
 <?php   get_posts(); ?>
```

instead of

```
<?php query_posts('post_type=post&posts_per_page=5&paged='.get_query_var('paged')); ?>
```

the posts are not showing.

Since everyone suggests that `get_posts()` is preferable in general over `query_posts()`, I wonder how can I have the posts showing, using `get_posts()`.

Comment: `query_posts()` does alter the main query, which is the reason that works for you - you still shouldn't use `query_posts()` though. Take a look at the `get_posts()` and `WP_Query` and `pre_get_posts` documentation to know your options.

Comment: I certainly looked at [get_posts()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts) but couldn't understand why it doesn't get the posts in my case.

Comment: sorry, no time to teach you, otherwise I would have written an answer, but if you look at the documentation it should be clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thing is that, contrary to popular belief, `pre_get_posts` does not work for single Page requests.[1](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts) Not even for is_front_page().

As for `get posts()`, in order to work I needed to use a syntax like:

```
<?php global $post;
$myposts = get_posts();
foreach( $myposts as $post ) :  setup_postdata($post); ?>
    ...
<?php endforeach; 
wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

instead of

```
<?php get_posts(); while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
...
```

Answer (score 1):

Every page has a "main query" which is run before the template is loaded. The results of the main query are how WordPress determines what template to load. The standard Loop operates on the data contained in the main query, this is why it seems to just magically "work" without you having to explicitly query something yourself.

`query_posts` overwrites the contents of that main query. This is why you shouldn't use `query_posts`- you're changing the query results after the template is loaded, which can have unexpected consequences. `pre_get_posts` is the preferred way to modify the main query, it runs before the main query happens, so that everything that follows is operating on the correct set of data.

`get_posts` and `WP_Query` are for running *additional* queries, separate from the main query. You have to assign the results to a variable, and run some sort of loop on those results. Your use of `get_posts` is doing nothing, because you've done nothing with the results of that query.